# ResponseRedirect fails when source url path contains http://

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

As part of an imageprocessing module I accept urls in the following format in order to process and cache externally hosted images.

```
http://localhost:56639/remote.axd/http://ipcache.blob.core.windows.net/source/IMG_0671.JPG?width=400&filter=comic
```

After processing the file, if I use `Response.Redirect(url, false)` to redirect the server to a valid external cache url, the server returns a 404 error response citing the StaticFileHandler as the source of the error.

If the file comes from a local source something like.

```
http://localhost:56639/IMG_0671.JPG?width=400&filter=comic
```

The server redirects to the external url without issue. Can someone explain why and provide a solution?

**Note**: `remote.axd` does nothing other than allow the local server to intercept the external url. I use the `.axd` extension as it isn't mapped to  route by default in MVC.

I've noticed that when looking at the request path the `http://` segment is replaced with `http:/`. I don't know whether that causes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

So the reference to StaticFileHandler is the clue.

Following the actions of my HttpModule the handler is attempting to process the request. When a locally cached file is used this finds the file and all is ok. Since I am redirecting to a remote url and have a remote source the handler is finding nothing and throwing a 404 exception.

Further processing of the request has to be halted following a rewrite using the following method.

#### [HttpApplication.CompleteRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx)